# Partial Averaging - Information and conditioning

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability

$$ \int_A E[X|G](\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_A X(\omega)dP(\omega) $$
for all sets A belong to Sigma algebra G.

**Quote from Steven Shreve’s Bk 2**

> - Say G is sigma algebra generated by some random variable W i.e. (G= σ(W))
> - E[X|G] is G-measurable
>
> This property ensures that E[X|G] is indeed an estimate of X. It gives the same averages as X over all the sets in G. If G has many sets, which provide a fine resolution of the uncertainty inherent in w (omega), then this partial-averaging property over the small sets in G says that the E[X|G] is good estimator of X. If G has only a few sets, this partial-averaging property guarantees only that E[X|G] is a crude of X.
> The above definition raises two immediate questions.
>
> - First, does there always exist a random variable E[X|G] satisfying the above properties above.
> - Second, if there is a random variable satisfying these properties is it unique?
>
> The answer to the first question is yes, and the proof of the existence of E[X|G] is based on the Radon-Nikodym Theorem
> The answer to the second is a qualified yes, as explained below.
> Suppose Y and Z both satisfy the above two conditions. Because both Y and Z are G-measurable, their difference (Y – Z) as well, and thus the set A = {Y-Z > 0} is in G. From the above equation we have
>
> $$ \int_A Y(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_A X(\omega)dP(\omega) = \int_A Z(\omega)dP(\omega) $$
> And thus
> $$ \int_A (Y(\omega) - Z(\omega))dP(\omega) =  0 $$

I am not clear what the above property wants to establish.
Is there a way anyone can convey the above message in a simple language? Use a simple language to draw an analogy?
Hope some of the experts help me get over this understanding gap!
I cannot skip this topic as this repeats in Chapter 5 Girsanov’s theorem (Risk Neutral measure)
Kindly guide/help me.

Also, many thanks to those who came up with the idea of this website/forum. It is so much easy to post a question with mathematical formula.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In the textbook $\textbf{Probability Theory and Examples }$ 5th edition by Rick Durrett, on page 178, there is the definition of the conditional expectation and there is proof on existence and uniqueness property. You should take a deep look at this chapter before learning Martingale.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been working on other chapters of Steven Shreve. Hence I could not respond. I purchased the kindle version of the above book. 
Pg 178 is discussing about Poisson process and I could not locate anything about Partial averaging. 
Can you please recheck, what you have mentioned. If possible please give me the section number/name as this would help me locate the content better. Thank you